# Problem signing PDF with iText, PKCS11 and SHA-256 Algorithm

Tags: itext, token, signature, sign, pkcs#11

I'm trying to sign a pdf using PCKS11 (USB Token) and iText, It works fine when I use SHA-1 algorithm, the signature is valid and everything works fine however when I change it to SHA256 the signature is not valid, Does anyone know why? I'll put my code below:

```
PKCS11 pkcs11 = PKCS11.getInstance("C:\\Windows\\System32\\example.dll", "C_GetFunctionList", null,false);
long[] slotList = pkcs11.C_GetSlotList(true);
String providerString = "name=*\nlibrary=C:\\Windows\\System32\\example.dll\n" + "slot=" + slotList [0];
SunPKCS11 sunPKCS11 = new SunPKCS11(new ByteArrayInputStream(providerString .getBytes()));
Provider provider = sunPKCS11;

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", provider);
keyStore.load(null, password);
keyStore.aliases();


Security.addProvider(keyStore.getProvider());

List<String> aliases = Collections.list(keyStore.aliases());
String alias = aliases.get(0);

PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)keyStore.getKey(alias,password);

Certificate[] certChain = new Certificate[1];
certChain[0] = signerCert;

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputData);

ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
    
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, outStream, '\0',null,true);
    
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();

String fieldName = keyStore.getCertificateAlias(signerCert).replaceAll(".","");

appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(420, 10, 70, 85), pageNumber,fieldName);

ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256,
          keyStore.getProvider().getName());

    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance,
                digest, es,
                certChain, null,
                null, null,
                0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
      
    return outStream.toByteArray();
```

Why does it work with SHA-1 and not SHA-2? Where do you think the problem arises?

Comment: Which algorithms does `example.dll` support?

Comment: It DOES support SHA256 for the hash and also SHA256RSA for the signature algorithm.

Comment: Please share an example pdf signed using sha256 for analysis.

Comment: So I changed my hash and now adobe shows who signed it (cause it used to be unknown) and also adobe shows that the hash algorithm is SHA256 which it didn't show before and now adobe says "The document has been altered since...". I changed my hash like this: MessageDigest _digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[]        hash   = _digest.digest(sh); -------------------------------- my pdf: https://file.io/BAvRbgT7RbyB

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yRVkf1aOdXfwJ0qOHsA_jMTEy0FsGJd5/view

Comment: *"I changed my hash like this..."* - It is completely unclear where in your original code you put that.

Answer (score 0):

There are mismatches and errors in your signature.

## [download.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yRVkf1aOdXfwJ0qOHsA_jMTEy0FsGJd5/view)

This is the example file you shared in a comment to your question

#### Mismatch of Document Digest

The SHA-256 hash value of the signed bytes of your PDF is

```
9356BCD36F172806A3DCE7F062A66441E7C1DDC9203ABDAA0154A3F19208C8E3
```

but the embedded signature container claims it to be

```
5F892978FF2459157D631809A05F5DBCFCB55800236D2D5C3E4E4D94577012B4
```

According to your code that should not happen. Are you sure that PDF has been created by the code in your question? Or have you somehow changed it as you indicated by your `I changed my hash like this` comment and created the example document thereafter? Then this discrepancy most likely is caused by your change.

#### Broken Raw RSA Signature

After decrypting the raw signature bytes and removing the padding one gets

```
3031300D0609608648016503040201050004201DC71B824BAA3C7EC6744A0941CFADDAA893E8C1
```

This is incomplete. It corresponds to

```asn
SEQUENCE (2 elem)
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha-256 (NIST Algorithm)
    NULL
  OCTET STRING (32 byte) 1DC71B824BAA3C7EC6744A0941CFADDAA893E8C1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

with the 12 bytes for that `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` piece missing.

Thus, it looks like the signing device does not really support SHA256withRSA, at least not in combination with the `example.dll` PKCS#11 driver and the `SunPKCS11` security provider.

As an aside, the OCTET STRING there should have been

```
EC7FCC5D003DFEC58B0ECB49CEEAD28495FFA8D798A1A88DA6051C1857B971EC
```

Thus, it looks like here is another mismatch, the `1DC71B824BAA3C7EC6744A0941CFADDAA893E8C1` actually there appears not to be related to this value.

## [SHA256.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hoj_sReCwizlYD1q5pPhy2BqwfoQKLpW/view?usp=sharing)

> Can you check out this one? this one is made with itext's library and no code was changed.

In this file there indeed are no hash mismatches anymore, merely the signature value is cut off, here

```
3031300D0609608648016503040201050004204C8440B547E6A0EFD1489B8F5B5DFDA2DFA45DC1
```

corresponding to

```
SEQUENCE (2 elem)
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha-256 (NIST Algorithm)
    NULL
  OCTET STRING (32 byte) 4C8440B547E6A0EFD1489B8F5B5DFDA2DFA45DC1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The complete OCTET STRING should have been

```
4C8440B547E6A0EFD1489B8F5B5DFDA2DFA45DC19048B5E53D468FE6A8E4E973
```

So apparently indeed the chain of your signing device, the `example.dll` PKCS#11 driver, and the `SunPKCS11` security provider from your JRE does not support SHA256withRSA.

Comment: I do KNOW that our USB token DOES support the SHA256withRSA and I do know that people do it right now so yeah thank you for your help. Let me look at this for now I'll reply if something came up.

Comment: Can you check out this one? this one is made with itext's library and no code was changed. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hoj_sReCwizlYD1q5pPhy2BqwfoQKLpW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *"I do KNOW that our USB token DOES support the SHA256withRSA and I do know that people do it right now"* - that's why i wrote *《at least not in combination with the example.dll PKCS#11 driver and the SunPKCS11 security provider.》* In particular the SunPKCS11 provider is far from perfect.

Comment: @Farzanenia Indeed, that file is better. Maybe Adobe Reader in this file gets further in its analysis and, therefore, eventually looks at the decrypted signature value. Because that value is syntactically broken, it shows less information on the signature dialogs than in the other case in which hash discrepancies were found.

Comment: @Farzanenia Can you give more information on your setup? Which JRE do you use?Which token exactly do you use? Do you have documentation on its algorithm support?

Comment: I think the problem lies within iText, Anyway I did it using native PKCS11 and older version of iText. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: *"I think the problem lies within iText"* - Well, no, iText does not work at that low level. *"Anyway I did it using native PKCS11 and older version of iText"* - Most likely your using *native PKCS11* calls PKCS#11 methods differently than the SunPKCS11 driver. Thus, you didn't have to switch to an older iText.

Comment: Well you're right I didn't have to switch to older version, however the problem DOES lie within iText.

Comment: @Farzanenia *"however the problem DOES lie within iText"* - No, not the *Broken Raw RSA Signature* problem: If low-level signature creation code creates RSA signature broken like that, then the low level signature creation code is broken. And that low-level code here is located in the PKCS#11 driver in question or maybe in parts in the SunPKCS11 security provider. iText in particular does not partake in this low level signature creation. And even if a different way to interface with PKCS#11 can create valid signatures, the error above still is in the driver/provider combination.

Comment: @Farzanenia That is not to say that iText signature creation code has no bugs. It does have bugs; in particular in the choice of signature algorithm OID entry and in the missing RSASSA-PSS support. Merely the bug your question is about is not an iText bug as far as one can tell from the data you provide.

Comment: Yes I guess that exactly it, the provider.

Comment: @Farzanenia which version of iText did you used to resolve the problem? I am also facing this issue while working with SUNPKCS11 provider.